# Set VLC (Videolan) as default video player but show video preview instead of vlc icon in explorer

Tags: windows-xp, vlc-media-player, windows-explorer

I just installed Videolan on a Windows XP machine and all the videos have now its cone logo instead of a preview of the video in windows explorer.

How can I change that while keeping Videolan as the default video player?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install any number of different Codec packs that handle this - [CCCP](http://www.cccp-project.net/), [K-Lite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Lite_Codec_Pack), etc.

It's worth noting that most of the codec packs will (by default, at least), install loads of extra stuff that you probably don't need. Be sure to choose custom install and just use what you need.

Comment: So, I have to install those codecs even if don't use them because VLC handles everything I have).

Comment: You DO use them - for thumbnail generation. To get a thumbnail you must decode the video as well, and the only supported mechanism is via codecs.